# Подскажите, как оптимизировать код

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, tkinter, инспекция-кода

Написал программу для создания массива из байтов
[image: Вот скриншот программы]

Вот сам код, подскажите если его можно как-то оптимизировать, формат выводимых на экран результатов менять нельзя, буду рад любым комментариям и советам.

P.S.  Готовый код тоже принимается

```
import tkinter as tk                #Для работы с графической частью приложения
import pyperclip                    #Для работы с буфетом обмена
 
root = tk.Tk()                      
root.geometry('435x290')
root.title('Symbols')

buttons = {}                        #Словарь для хранения позиций и характеристик кнопок
output = []                     #Необработаный двумерный массив состояний кнопок 
stage2 = []                         #Это массив преобразует каждый вложенный список предыдущего элемента в список с одним элементом
stage3 = []                         #Этот список преобразует предыдущий в одномерный список
result = []                         #Преобразует предыдущий список, в список с одним элементом

class Button():
    def __init__(self, y, x, color):
        '''Создаем кнопку, задаем положение и начальный цвет'''
        self.button = tk.Button(root, width = 2, bg = color , command = lambda: self.check(self.button, y, x, color))   #Создаем кнопку и задаем ей команду при нажатии
        buttons.update({str(y)+str(x): self.button})        #Добавляем кнопку в словарь с ключем равным координатам

    def check(self, button, y, x, color):
        button.destroy()    #Удаляем переданую в функцию кнопку, чтобы потом создать на ее месте новую с другим цветом

        if (color == '#dadada'):    #Меняем цвет кнопки и ее состояние на противоположное
           color = '#00a03e'
           state = '1'
        else: 
            color = '#dadada'
            state = '0'

        output[y][x+2] = state      #Заменяем состояние кнопки в массиве состояний всех кнопок исходя из координат кнопки

        self.button = tk.Button(root, width = 2, bg = color, command = lambda: self.check(self.button, y, x, color))    #Создаем кнопку с тем же положением, но с другим цветом 
        buttons.update({str(y)+str(x): self.button})    #Передобавляем кнопку в словарь с ключом равным координатам
        build()     #Обращаемся к функции отрисовки



for y in range(8):          #Этот блок заполняет словарь кнопок в первый раз
    for x in range(8):
        Button(y, x, '#dadada')

for i in range(8):          #Создаем двумерный масив состояний кнопок
     output.append(list('0b'+'0'*8))        #"0b" -- формат записи последовательности байтовб "0*8" -- записываем в каждый подсписок пустую 8-ми битную последовательность

def build():
    '''Функция отрисовки интерфейса программы'''
    for i in buttons:
        '''Берем каждую кнопку из словаря и задаем ей положение и отступ на окне программы'''
        buttons.get(i).grid(row = i[0], column = i[1], padx = 5, pady = 5)

    Labela = tk.Label(root, text = 'Result', width = 20)        #Просто надпись
    text = tk.Text(root, width = 12, height = 10)               #Поле для вывода результатов
    text.insert(3.0, resultshow())                              #Добавляем в предыдущее поле текст и указываем размер, resultshow() возвращает нам конечный результат
    btn = tk.Button(root, text = 'Clear', width = 10, bg = 'blue', fg = 'white', command = lambda:clean())      #Кнопка для возвращения к  первичному состоянию всех кнопок 
    copybtn = tk.Button(root, text = 'Copy', width = 10, bg = '#54e874', fg = 'white', command = lambda: pyperclip.copy(resultshow()))  #Кнопка для занесения результатов в буфет обмена

    '''Далее идет расстановка, на окне программы, выше указанных элементов меню'''
    Labela.grid(row = 0, column = 8, sticky = tk.S, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    text.grid(row = 1, column = 8, rowspan = 5, sticky = tk.N, padx = 5, pady= 5)
    btn.grid(row = 7, column = 8, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    copybtn.grid(row = 6, column = 8, padx = 5, pady = 5)

def clean():
    '''Функция для возвращения всех кнопок к первичному состоянию'''
    buttons.clear()     #Удаляем содержимое словаря с кнопками для дальнейшего пере наполнения
    output.clear()      #Удаляем содержимое двумерного массив состояний для дальнейшего пере наполнения

    for i in range(8):
        '''Перезаполняем двумерный массив состояний кнопок'''
        output.append(list('0b'+'0'*8))

    '''После удаление содержимого массива с кнопами, заново наполняем его'''
    for x in range(8):
        for y in range(8):
                        Button(x, y, '#dadada')

    build()     #Стерев все данные копок и создав новые, возвращаемся к функции отрисовки


def resultshow():
    for q in output:
        '''Преобразуем каждый вложенный список списка output в список с одним элементом'''
        stage1 = ''.join(q)         #Тут происходит склейка элементов вложенного списка
        stage2.append(stage1)       #Добавляем каждый список с одним элементом во второй вспомогательный список

   stage3.append('{')               #Особенности оформления конечного результата
    stage3.append('},')             #Особенности оформления конечного результата

    for e in stage2:
        '''Берем единственный элемент каждого вложенного списка, и добавляем оформление и отступы, после чего добавляем в третий вспомогательный список'''
        stage3.insert(-1, e + ', ')

    result = ''.join(stage3)    #Склеиваем все элементы третьего вспомогательного списка

    '''Удаляем содержимое вспомогательных списков, чтобы избежать ошибок'''
    stage2.clear()
    stage3.clear()

    return result       #Возвращаем конечный результат

build()     #Первичный запуск программы отрисовки

root.mainloop()
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Так код понравился)Может вместо динамических массивов т.е. работающих через append, сделать статические возможно более длинные чем нужно и заполнять их.

Comment: Да, взять numpy массив 2-мерный, да работать с ним. list + append это долго

Comment: Недостатки кода: глобальные переменные; лишние действия в коде; лишние параметры; функции, выполняющие слишком много работы; сам код разбросан.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю такой код (как избавиться от глобальных `text` и `buttons` не смог придумать):

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyperclip


def main():
    global text, buttons
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('435x290')
    root.title('Symbols')

    text = tk.Text(root, width=12, height=10)  # text field for output 
    buttons = [[Button(x, y) for x in range(8)] for y in range(8)]  # buttons list 
    show_result()
    
    text.grid(row=1, column=8, rowspan=5, sticky=tk.N, padx=5, pady=5)
    tk.Label(root, text='Result', width=20).\
        grid(row=0, column=8, sticky=tk.S, padx=5, pady=5)
    tk.Button(root, text='Clean', width=10, bg='blue', fg='white', command=lambda: reset(buttons)).\
        grid(row=7, column=8, padx=5, pady=5)  # Clean button
    tk.Button(root, text='Copy', width=10, bg='#54e874', fg='white', command=lambda: pyperclip.copy(text.get(1.0, tk.END))).\
        grid(row=6, column=8, padx=5, pady=5)  # Copy button
    for btn_row in buttons:
        for btn in btn_row:
            btn.grid(row=btn.y, column=btn.x, padx=5, pady=5)
            
    root.mainloop()


class Button(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(width=2, bg='#dadada', command=lambda: self.change_state())
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.state = '0'

    def change_state(self):
        if self.state == '1':
            self['bg'] = '#dadada'
            self.state = '0'
        elif self.state == '0':
            self['bg'] = '#00a03e'
            self.state = '1'
        show_result()

    def reset(self):
        self['bg'] = '#dadada'
        self.state = '0'


def show_result():
    result = '{'
    for row in buttons:
        result += '0b'
        for btn in row:
            result += btn.state
        result += ', '
            
    result = result[:-2]+' },'
    text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    text.insert(3.0, result)


def reset(buttons):
    for row in buttons:
        for btn in row:
            btn.reset()

main()
```